# calling webapi in form closing event does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core-webapi, formclosing

Trying to capture that user logged out when the Winform application is closed. From the client form, `orm_Closing` event is fired but the `HttpClient.PostAsync` call stops and the webapi never receive the post at all.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseAsString);
        }
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Async/Await` for that call. The application ends before the request on the background thread completes.

Make it a synchronous call. That way it will be executed on the Main UI thread which will have to wait for the webapi response before the process is terminated.

Comment: As a good rule of thumb, any event handler with mutable properties (e.g. `CancelEventArgs.Cancel`) must be called synchronously and cannot use `await`.

Comment: is it ok if  using await when calling
private async void MainForm2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {            
            await logService.Info("User logged out");
        }

Comment: @beewest remove the `async/await` from that event.